# ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I'm using the SQL Server 2008  installed in a remote desktop. And I am trying to access it using PHP.

I have downloaded the PHP drivers. The Registered PHP Streams in phpinfo includes sqlsrv.

So if the following error pops the ODBC driver should be installed in my system or in remote desktop. I'm using PHP Version 7.0.8, so I need ODBC Driver 11 or 13?

```
Connection failureArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMSSP
            [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
            [1] => -49
            [code] => -49
            [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
           [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => IM002
            [SQLSTATE] => IM002
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
        )

)
```